# How to describe different levels of maturity?

Tags: adjectives

The dictionary describes *mature* as *fully developed, completed, or perfected*. I assume by this meaning that it is already absolute.

My question is, is there such thing as degrees of maturity? If yes, what are those adverbs to describe the degrees of maturity?

Comment: You have to mean adverbs, not adjectives, as in "more mature", "less mature", "very mature", "somewhat mature", "extremely mature", "fully mature". If you do mean adjectives, as in "childish", "developed", "ripening", then the question is off-topic as too broad. There are any number of equally valid answers.

Comment: As 'mature' _does_ have an extreme definition, the use of degree modifiers is perverse – but it is extremely common. Just like the use of the word 'fuller'. 'Fuller' doesn't make sense when you think about it; we use it as an abbreviated form of 'more nearly full'. Similarly, 'more mature' is really shorthand for 'more nearly mature'. However, I wouldn't be surprised to see a non-extreme definition of 'mature' as 'well along the path to maturity'.

Comment: I have already edited the question @RegDwigнt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are absolutely gradations of [maturity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maturity_%28psychological%29).  That is why we use phrases like *more mature*, *less mature*, *immature*, etc.

Typically, maturity is described in stages.  For example, when describing physical maturity we use the [Tanner Scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanner_scale).

There are also stages of psychological maturation as well.  For example, [Erikson's stages of psychosocial development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erikson%27s_stages_of_psychosocial_development).

There are many, many other examples of staged gradations of maturity.  So, if you wish something more complex than *more, less, fully, etc.*, you will need to delve into the specific field you wish to describe its stages.

Answer (score 0):

**Childish/immature** is at one end of the spectrum, **juvenile** indicates the quality of not being completely **mature** and the transition from one end to the other and mature is the other end in this maturity spectrum.

The word **fledgling** might also indicate the beginning of this transition based on the context.